# ModuleNotFoundError: No module name states

Tags: python, module

This is my directory structure:

```html
.
└── Test_game
    ├── game_play.py
    ├── game.py
    ├── map
    │   └── map.png
    └── states
        ├── state.py
        └── title.py
```

When I try to import `State` into *title.py*:

```
from states.state import State
```

I get the same error in my *game.py*

```
from states.title import Title
```

I'm trying to make multiple game states, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I also tried to `pip3 install states` into the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to import from another file in the same directory. The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use relative imports, i.e. don't use `from states.state import State`, but only use `from .state import State` (without states at the beginning).

The problem you're facing is that you are inside a folder (btw: even not being a package, because no `__init__.py` is found) and want to search the folder path up. There is obviously no search path configured that let you do this. But this is okay, because the target module on the same folder (which you want to import) is always on the search path of the source module (where you want to import). So you can simply make use of Python's relative imports abilities.

If you want to read more, here is the [Python documentation about the import statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) and even further [a tutorial about packaging](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/), which could also be of interest.